# setMarkerClickListener desaparece Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-drawerlayout, floating-action-button

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Kotlin la cual luce de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se observa que el boton de geolocalización en la esquina superior aparece. Sin embargo al agregar un FloatingButton; éste desaparece como la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón de geolocalización desaparece. ¿Hay alguna forma de poder solucionar esto y agregar el FloatingButton sin que desaparezca el botón de geolocalización? ¿Podrían darme alguna orientación?

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="13"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="500dp"
            >
        </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

El botón de Geolocalización permanece con este XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="13"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>                   
</LinearLayout>
```

He intentado adaptar algunos ejemplos similares, pero estoy un poco atascado en esto.
Gracias.

Fuentes consultadas:
[Android Google Map - Map Type selection from FAB menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032235/android-google-map-map-type-selection-from-fab-menu/60424841?noredirect=1#comment106893999_60424841)

**EDICIÒN:**

Agrego dos funciones especiales relacionadas con el marker desde mi `Mainactivity.kt`:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap //Princiapal Map Variable
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this) //Location Marker
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true //Zoom in maps enabled
        setUpMap() //Function to detect actual location
    }

 private fun setUpMap() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, //Check if the permission was granted by user in actual installation
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { //if isn't
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, //Require permission
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true //Layer draws a blue dot like user location, also create user's location button to reach it.
        //mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE //Gives different maptypes
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { //Gives the most recently location available
                location ->
            if(location != null)
            {
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLastLong = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLastLong, 12f)) //Default 17f

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setMarkerClickListener` es el método donde se define el listener del marcador, al dar clic sobre elelmento, NO es un marcador.

Lo que sucede regularmente es que se crea un marcador pero la cámara no se mueve hacia ese punto, por esta razón no se visualiza el marcador.

**Al definir el `Marker` (marcador) te sugiero mover la cámara usando el método `moveCamera()` para que puedas visualizar el marcador creado.**

Este es un ejemplo en **Java**:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Agrega Marcador a Guadalajara, Mexico,
    // y mueve la camara a la posición
    LatLng guadalajara = new LatLng(20.6636993,-103.3637399);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(guadalajara)
            .title("Guadalajara"));

    //Mueve camara
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(guadalajara, 14f));

}
```

Este es un ejemplo en **Kotlin**:

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
        // Agrega Marcador a Guadalajara, Mexico,
        // y mueve la camara a la posición
    val guadalajara = LatLng(20.66, -103.36)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(guadalajara).title("Guadalajara"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(guadalajara))
  }
```

Revisa también:

[Cómo configurar los limites de la vista googleMaps en un fragment, Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96607/c%c3%b3mo-configurar-los-limites-de-la-vista-googlemaps-en-un-fragment-android-studi)

[Mostrar varios markers almacenados en un array en el mapa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91173/mostrar-varios-markers-almacenados-en-un-array-en-el-mapa)

Comment: He modificado el .kt a mi còdigo, pero si sin aparecer el botòn de location.

Comment: agrega como creas el marker

Comment: Listo, @Jorgesys

Comment: Veo que estas usando Kotlin, el problema es que no estas creando un Marcador: googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(guadalajara)
            .title("Guadalajara"));

Comment: He buscado ejemplos como crear variables Latlng pero no logro conseguirlo, podrìas orientame en eso? Siento no haber especifícado que era en Kotlin.

Comment: Agregue un ejemplo en Kotlin a mi respuesta @Mareyes Aquí un ejemplo en Kotlin: https://www.raywenderlich.com/230-introduction-to-google-maps-api-for-android-with-kotlin

Comment: precisamente estaba siguiendo ese tutorial hace tiempo. Seguiré investigando, igual forma daré tu respuesta como correcta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Solo recuerda que esta linea crea el marcador, si no la tienes no se visualizara: mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(guadalajara).title("Guadalajara"))